# PHP Template Patterns UI and Content Decoupling

Tags: php, templates, design-patterns, user-interface

With respect,

I am looking for a way to organize my HTML markup within PHP for use in a website which delivers dominantly static content(read: for a .edu website). (While this is the main thrust for this question, I am definitely interested in the non-static case as well since I may at some point soon "need" to deal with sessions and user login events etc)

The pattern I have often seen used for PHP (and other languages like Coldfusion, .NET, etc) is as follows:

```
// define header stub in header.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="headerWrapper">
            <!-- header content goes here -->
        </div>
        <div id="contentWrapper">
// end header stub

// define footer stub in footer.php
        </div><!-- end contentWrapper -->
        <div id="footer">
            <!-- footer content goes here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
// end footer stub
```

To use this pattern, I would define a content file thusly:

```
// define content stub in contentFile.php
<?php include("header.php") ?>
            <p>hello world</p>
            <!-- other content goes here -->
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
// end content stub
```

I am looking for more. The problem I have with the above example is the level of coupling required by the general pattern. That is, there are some significant dependencies between header.php and footer.php for example (namely page structure, the dangling contentWrapper div tags, and, on a lower level, the inevitable css and js includes that are not required by every page). I am looking specifically for encapsulation. My ideal content page would look like this:

```
    // ideal.php
    <?php
        $someObj.pageTitle="My First Page!!!";
        $someObj.headInclude("/css/960.css");
        $someObj.headInclude("/js/myFancyThing.js");
        $someObj.preferedTemplate = "default"; /* or maybe "MathDept" or something like that */
    ?>
    <!-- page content goes here, just semantic and structural markup, let the 
template handle H1 and Paragraph formatting :) -->
    // end ideal stub
```

This last pattern is something I would very much like to see. It seems to me a much more elegant solution for the decoupling of content from presentation. I don't know how to articulate this in PHP but I suspect it is feasible. Any help would be most appreciated! Thank you!!! :)

/* I hope what I have asked is appropriately scoped and titled. Please forgive me otherwise; I am still a bit green with Stack Exchange, PHP and pretty much everything lol */

Comment: use al library like smarty , symfony/templating or twig. want to know how it is done ? like at the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the response mpm. I have looked at Smarty and a few other frameworks. For the frameworks I have seen, all seem to take care of the decoupling I am after to various degrees. The reason I have not pursued any of them is because I want to build up a better understanding of PHP and its request life cycle. That is, I want to reasonably understand what I am getting myself into by going with a particular framework. Your suggestion to check out the source code for Smarty or one of the other frameworks is a good one and one I will pursue.

Comment: the template engine you might use has nothing to do with PHP request lifecycle , it just echoes some strings. And "PHP request lifecycle" is barebone , nothing really complicated here. The best way to learn how to code is not by starting from scratch but by reading other people's code. If you would have read any php template library you would have learned about php buffers ( ob_start() , ... ) already. But you did not , so you dont know about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this kind of (excellent) thinking and approach you'll very quickly find yourself reinventing the MVC design pattern. I would strongly suggest you look at the Zend Framework's approach to the presentation layer. They use a two step design (layout + view). Here's a simplistic example of the pattern:

Controller:

```
public function someAction()
{
    // Add the CSS files.
    $this->view->headLink()
        ->appendStylesheet($this->view->baseUrl() . '/css/site.css')
        ->appendStylesheet($this->view->baseUrl() . '/css/ie6.css', 'screen', 'IE 6')
        ->appendStylesheet($this->view->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery/plugins/ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css', 'screen')

    // Add the JavaScript files.
    $this->view->headScript()
        ->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')
        ->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery/plugins/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js')
        ->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl() . '/js/modernizr.js');

    // Add the meta tags.
    $this->view->headMeta()
        ->appendHttpEquiv('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=edge')
        ->appendName('description', '...')
        ->appendName('keywords', '...');

    // Render the View.
    $this->view->render();
}
```

Layout:

```
<?php
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
echo $this->doctype(); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink();?>
    <?php echo $this->headScript();?>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="wrapper">

        <?php echo $this->partial('partials/header.phtml');?>

        <?php echo $this->layout()->content;?>

        <?php echo $this->partial('partials/footer.phtml');?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

View:

```
<h1>This View script is rendered by the View and will get injected into the layout.</h1>
<div>Page specific markup goes in this file</div>
```

If you do decide to go down this route, think hard before writting the framework code yourself.

Link: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html

Comment: Thank you for the response Jon. This is definitely in line with what I would like to see as an end result. Is there a way to achieve this with pure PHP(ie: no prepackaged framework)? /* thinking I need to refactor my question to reflect this intent. Sorry if this was misleading */

Comment: Thank you Jon. I deleted the post initially because I thought I had made a mistake by asking what I did(was embarrassed). As it turns out, you were quite right.

Comment: With your help and some of the comments from mpm, I ended up implementing my ideal case using output buffering and the auto_prepend_file directive to introduce a passive controller.

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted a simple version of my implementation at [this Stack Overflow article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123285/php-pattern-to-decouple-ui-markup-from-static-content) for review. It has been up for a bit without negative feedback so I assume I didn't do anything catastrophically wrong lol.